# Making REST calls more efficient

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest

So I have a microservice which return JSON objects and uses basic authentication.

Then I have a Springboot client app that will do a GET or POST call to the service.

1) The client will POST /login and then store the credentials in the client app

2) Then on every GET or POST call, the basic header will be added programmatically and call the service using RestTemplate.

For example, a user tries to get an item:

1) GET http://client/item/{id} through an ajax call

2) The client app will do a RestTemplate call to the service http://service/item/{id}

So I am writing all the mappings 2 times... I don't want to expose the authentication details in js, and the service might return tokens or info that I would store in the client app.

Am I doing something wrong? Im using HTML with Thymeleaf.

Comment: Rather than saving credentials (original), your /login service could return a tokenized value (based on current http session and other login values). You can use this tokenized unique value for next API call. The next API if needed may return new token etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a greenfield project, I would suggest to move to Angular or ReactJs+Redux or similar sorts rather than using thymeleaf.

But that's a different discussion. Coming back to your question, what is the reason for you to have 2 different apps? why can't you move all the service(http://service/item) endpoints to client (http://client). Is both service(http://service/item) and client (http://client) is owned by you or your team?

If there is compelling need to keep both service(http://service/item) and client (http://client) separate, this is code repetition is something that you should be willing to pay, [its the curse of Microservices](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2012/11/28/micro-services-the-curse-of-code-duplication/).

Other perspective is, you don't necessarily have to treat it as code repetition, assume that service(http://service/item) is in Java and client (http://client) is in NodeJs, then chances are very less that you will consider it as repeating yourself.

You can reduce the the code repetition to a bit by publishing the Java Model classes as a library and making use of that in both service(http://service/item) and client (http://client). I will discourage this pattern as you are tying your producer and consumer with same programming language.